# Background music becomes distorted when my sound fx fire

Tags: javascript, audio, html5-canvas, 2d-games

I have a javascript game that plays background music when the game starts

index.js

```
//background music
window.music = new Audio(ASSETURLS.song)
...
music.volume = .25
music.play();
```

game.js

```
//when the bullet is fired, render it on the screen
bullet.placeAt(this.player.tileFrom[0] + (DIRECTIONS[bullet.facing].DIRS[0]), this.player.tileFrom[1] + (DIRECTIONS[bullet.facing].DIRS[1]))
//play this sound
gameSoundFx("singleShot")
this.bullets.push(bullet)
```

util.js

```
export const gameSoundFx = (assetKey) => {
  let audio = new Audio(ASSETURLS[assetKey])
  if (assetKey === "singleShot") {
    audio.volume = .5
  } else {
    audio.volume = .15
  }
  audio.play()
}
```

The music and the sound affects will play no problem, but whenever I fire the bullet the background music becomes distorted. I cant tell if this is some kind of issue with resource usage or if I need to set up the sound assets differently. I tried searching for this issue and I cant seem to find a lot of information about it.

You can see a live demo [here](https://drice89.github.io/grimdark/) if you want to actually hear the sound distortion.

Comment: I don't hear any distortion. Tried in Firefox 79.0 and Chromium 84.0 on Arch Linux.

Comment: You dont hear it breaking the music up? it sounds like the background music is stuttering? Im on a MBP.

Comment: No, I don't hear that, it keeps the beat nicely and does not stutter even when smashing the space bar repeatedly. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Yes I tried firefox and had the same issue. I must have a problem with the computer.